# Web Services- Single instance or multiple

Tags: java, web-services, jakarta-ee

I have developed one web service using Axis 1.1 which has 2 operations one which gives the list of items and other which adds an item in the array. Everything is working fine but my doubt is when i am deploying that service in Glassfish 4 then after adding an item in the array i am able to view that item which means only single instance is getting created of the service. But when i deploy in tomcat 7 then this is not happening.

Can anyone tell me when the web service is exposed then when it is called only one instance is created or for every request one instance gets created.(like multiple instances)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Axis makes a new object to service each request - this is the default. More information here http://axis.apache.org/axis/faq.html#faq8

Answer (score 0):

Instance will be created for every request and it is not like servlet specification and it doesn't any instance creation life like servlet.